# A code that is a word forwards & a different word backwards

Tags: language-agnostic, encode

For a present, I am trying to create a code that reads as a certain word forwards and a different word backwards. An example (0,1,2 are the available symbols):

D = 02, E = 01, H = 201, L = 1, O = 211, R = 10, W = 11

Then the pair "HELLO"/"WORLD" would be

> 2010111211 HELLO
>   1121110102 WORLD

I would like to generate a code that fits other word pairs. Obviously, I cannot brute force the solution (if one exists for that pair). All the optimization / search methods I know (simulated annealing, hill climbing, genetic algorithm) give me imperfect solutions only, if the word pairs are long.

The above example was found in a genetic algorithm I wrote to solve this, but after many generations with different parameters and word order, etc. it never quite reaches 100%.

How can I approach this differently? The length of each codeword <strike>is not very important</strike> should be less than 10 symbols per character, the number of different symbols used should stay under 5, and the code does not need to be prefix-free.

**Edit:** Following the comments, here is what I'm actually trying to do: Basically, I want to have a necklace with differently shaped beads (per symbol) that encode a word, and if you twist it then it encodes a different word. Therefore the codewords shouldn't be extremely long, and there cannot be too many different symbols.

**Edit 2:** Forwards, it should read FESTUNG DRESDEN (or FESTUNGDRESDEN), backwards some combination of generic "nice wishes", i.e. FRIENDS, FORTUNE, LUCK, HAPPINESS (or the German equivalent of these words) or just the name MARIA (yes, you've guessed right, it's for a girl...). It does not matter, if these words form pairs (i.e. FESTUNG reads backwards to FORTUNE, DRESDEN reads backwards to FRIENDS) or if it's the long version (i.e. FESTUNGDRESDEN reads backwards to FRIENDS&FORTUNE).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you need one code which will work for every possible pair of words? That won't be possible!

Comment: @Tom Gullen: a birthday present. Basically, I want to have a necklace with differently shaped beads that encode a word, and if you twist it then it encodes a different word.

@Moron: no, just one specific pair (but both words will be quite long [14 to 20 chars]).

Comment: @Duddle: Great idea! That means you need at least two symbols? I suggest you edit the question to say that. Also, what other kinds of 'twists' are you considering? Perhaps you should mention the necklace in the question! Would raise more interest...

Comment: If you only have one application ever being in mind, then perhaps you could provide the two words you are intending to encode?  If this is within my bounds of asking, of course.

Comment: @Duddle In your example the encoding does not seem to lead to unique decoding.
For example the words "LDLL"  and "RO" both encode to "10211". Is that what you are trying to get? Reading the beads will need a lot of guessing :)

Comment: @belisarius: You are right. I would prefer a prefix-free code for easier and unique decoding, but in the end it's more important if the words decode to the given word pairs at all.

Comment: @Duddle So you may want to design the code in such a way that also encodes your "nice wishes" phrase FORWARDS :D

Comment: @belisarius: I might not understand you correctly, but no. Think of a necklace: you read from left to right and decode the word. Then you twist/turn it so it's mirrored, and read different words from left to right.

Comment: @Duddle ahhh ... makes more sense now, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to transform FESTUNGDRESDEN into MARIA.

I found a possible encoding that does not satisfy all the specified conditions, since one of the letters needs more than 10 symbols.

**A "manual" procedure:** As both words share only one letter (the "R") I broke up  both words as follows

```
  --------------->
  FESTUNGD R ESDEN
    A I    R  A M
   <--------------
```

so, keeping the code for R as a palindrome

```
   cod(FESTUNGD) = cod*(IA)
   and
   cod(ESDEN) = cod*(MA)

   where cod*() means "reading the code backwards"
```

Then I divided the problem one step further splitting the codes for the E and T

```
  ----------------------------------->
  FES(T2) (T1)UNGD R ESD(E3) (E2)(E1)N
    A        I     R      A      M
   <----------------------------------
```

I think this could be a starting point for developing a "real" algorithm in the future.

Anyway, by doing so I was able to write down the equations for each encoded char. The only difficult part is the "A", since it is repeated. This leads to the following equation

```
  cod("FES") & (T2) = cod("ESD") & (E3)
```

Proceeding in a similar way (further splitting the codes for letter X in X(1) X(2) X(3)), I rewrote the above equation into sub-parts and solved it. Not difficult, but tedious.

The result is:

```
F= 21243
E= 2124
S= 3212
T= 125
U= 1
```

<strike>N= 4</strike>

```
G= 3
D= 4321
R= 33
N= 2

M= 24
A= 212123421234212 --> Here is the looong one
I= 12343215

So, when you read

      f     e    s    t   u n g d    r  e    s    d    e    n
      21243 2124 3212 125 1 2 3 4321 33 2124 3212 4321 2124 2
   <--------------------------------------------------------
   v  backwards is:
   |
   |  M  A               R  I        A 
   |  24 212123421234212 33 12343215 212123421234212
   ------------------------------------------------->
```

I think this solution doesn't contribute in the field of algorithm development, but hopefully it does in the better cause of love :)

> **EDIT > FRIENDSHIP**

Following the same procedure as above (and the suggestion made by Justin L.) , I tried with the word "Friendship", which seems aligned with the idea you want to communicate.

With the following table:

```
f 434
e 44
s 543
t 22
u 1
n 34
g 5
d 3
r 43

i 345
h 122
p 44434
```

The result is

```
       f   e  s   t  u  n   g  d  r  e   s    d   e   n
       434 44 543 22 1  34  5  3  43 44  543  3   44  34
   <-----------------------------------------------------
   v  and backwards is:
   |
   |   f   r   i   e   n   d  s   h   i   p
   |   434 43  345 44  34  3  543 122 345 44434
   ---------------------------------------------->
```

Please note that the equations for "t" "u" and "h" are independent from the rest of the system. So you can choose any unused combination of {3,4,5} (of any length) for them, possibly making the necklace with only 3 symbols. For doing this you could try

```
 t -> 4
 u -> 54

 which results in

 h -> 454

 all 3 are unused and available codes
```

Don't forget to upload a photo of the necklace!

Viel Glück!

**Edit 1.5 years later**

Here are two wonderful photographs taken by the OP with the results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 because it works; now just to find a proper backwards word or way to encode so that there all of the keys are short =(

Comment: Thank you! This answer is wunderbar. Just noticed that you have two "N" in the first solution, in the example it is correct though. I will try and see which of both examples work best, then make a photo. Thanks again.

Comment: @Duddle There was a spurious "n" in the previous solution encoding table. Surely something that made its way through the tidy up of the answer, but the encoding was right (at least I believe so). I am going to edit it. Thanks a lot for the correction.

Comment: Won't 21243 and 2124 lead to a conflict? The original post has the codes mashed together, how do you know in the string "2124321243" whether you have "2124 3 2124 3" or "21243 21243"?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen You are right, but the question specified that the prefix-free condition was not an issue (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code)

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen BTW, that is why the answer made by @Moron is also technically correct in spite of the "all beads are equal" aesthetical concern

Comment: Just a quick update, since you asked for it. This is the code-table: http://i.imgur.com/j4fwh.jpg and this is the bracelet in action: http://i.imgur.com/hLgl4.jpg (the photo is a bit unfavourable, though). Thanks again, you've helped make a woman happy :)

Comment: @Duddle Very nice! And surely the first bracelet in the world to come with a reference manual :D Thanks for the photos!

Comment: @Duddle I wanted to show your photos to a friend of mine, and found that the links are dead. Could you upload them again, please? Thanks!

Comment: @belisarius Haven't been logged in for a while, did not see your question from Oct. 2011. But you edited your answer in 2012 with the requested pictures, otherwise I'd upload them again if needed.

Answer (score 2):

If the code does not need to be prefix free and you don't care how long the codes are, then just one symbol is enough!

You encode each character by a different number of 1's, so that, in the end, the total number of 1s for one word is the same as the total number for the other.

To do this, remove the common characters.

In case of HELLO and WORLD, you are left with HEL and WRD.

Now you need six distinct integers which can be grouped into two groups of 3, such that sum of one group = sum of other.

One way to do this is to select odd numbers greater than 1 for one group and even numbers for the other (and possibly 1, depending on the number in each group).

For HEL and WRD you select

{3,5,7} and {1,6,8}.

For the common ones, now you can select numbers not in either group and you are done! (Although some care needs to be taken for words of very different length).

I have a feeling I have misunderstood something though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my specifications were not very well defined. Yes, I don't care much about codeword-length, but its real-world application (see edit) only permits a maximum length. Also, it should remain human-decodable (with a coding-table), so a "1-symbol-only"-code is very hard to decode. And it would not be pretty enough for the necklace (see edit) :)